# proto: cannot parse invalid wire-format data

Tags: c#, .net, go, protocol-buffers

I'm new to protobufs and currently writing a client which reads from a NATS server. The data being sent from the NATS server is a protobuf.

The client I'm writing is in Go. This is the .proto file I've written:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package execution;

option go_package = "./protos/execution";

enum OrderStatus {
  Working = 0;
  Rejected = 1;
  Cancelled = 2;
  Completed = 3;
}

enum OrderType {
  Limit = 0;
  Market = 1;
  StopLimit = 2;
  StopMarket = 3;
}

enum OrderSide {
  Buy = 0;
  Sell = 1;
}

enum RejectReason {
  NoRejection = 0;
  InstrumentNotFound = 1;
  OrderNotFound = 2;
  InvalidOrderType = 3;
  InvalidAccount = 4;
  InvalidSide = 5;
  InvalidAmount = 6;
  InvalidLimitPrice = 7;
  InvalidQuoteLimit = 8;
  InvalidActivationPrice = 9;
  InvalidTimeInForce = 10;
  MarketHalted = 11;
  MarketPaused = 12;
  NoCounterOrders = 13;
  MissingExpirationTime = 14;
  IncorrectExpirationTime = 15;
  InternalError = 16;
  IllegalStatusSwitch = 17;
  OrderAlreadyExists = 18;
  InstrumentNotReady = 19;
  ExternalSystemError = 20;
}

enum ReportCause {
  NONE = 0;
  NewOrder = 1;
  CancelOrder = 2;
  MassCancel = 3;
  Expiration = 4;
  Trigger = 5;
  MarketStatusChange = 6;
}

enum TimeInForce {
  GoodTillCancel = 0;
  ImmediateOrCancel = 1;
  FillOrKill = 2;
}

enum CancelReason {
  NotCancelled = 0;
  CancelledByTrader = 1;
  CancelledBySystem = 2;
  SelfMatchPrevention = 3;
  OrderTimeInForce = 4;
  Liquidation = 100;
}


message TradeData {
  int64 TradeId = 1;
  string Amount = 4;
  string ExecutionPrice = 5;
  OrderStatus OrderStatus = 7;
  int64 AccountId = 11;
  string MatchedOrderExternalId = 14;
  int64 MatchedOrderId = 16;
  string RemainingAmount = 17;
}

message Execution {
  string Origin = 4;
  OrderSide Side = 7;
  string RequestedPrice = 8;
  string RequestedAmount = 9;
  string RemainingAmount = 10;
  int64 ExecutedAt = 13;
  OrderStatus OrderStatus = 14;
  repeated TradeData Trades = 16;
  OrderType OrderType = 20;
  int64 Version = 22;
  int64 AccountId = 23;
  RejectReason RejectReason = 25;
  ReportCause ReportCause = 26;
  string InstructionId = 27;
  string ExternalOrderId = 28;
  int32 ExecutionEngineMarketId = 29;
  int64 OrderId = 30;
  CancelReason CancelReason = 31;
  int64 TxId = 32;
  TimeInForce TimeInForce = 34;
  string CancelledBy = 35;
}
```

The publishing server is written in C# and the code for their proto message is this:

```
[ProtoContract]
    public class ExecutionReport : IMarketResponse, IInstructionMessage, IOrderMatcherResponse
    {
        [ProtoIgnore]
        FeedMessageType IFeedMessage.Type => FeedMessageType.ExecutionReport;

        // ReSharper disable FieldCanBeMadeReadOnly.Global
        [ProtoMember(4)] public string Origin;
        [ProtoMember(7)] public OrderSide Side;
        [ProtoMember(8)] public decimal RequestedPrice;
        [ProtoMember(9)] public decimal RequestedAmount;
        [ProtoMember(10)] public decimal RemainingAmount;
        [ProtoMember(13)] public long ExecutedAt;
        [ProtoMember(14)] public OrderStatus OrderStatus;
        [ProtoMember(16)] public List<TradeData> Trades = new List<TradeData>();
        [ProtoMember(20)] public OrderType OrderType;
        [ProtoMember(22)] public long Version { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(23)] public long AccountId;
        [ProtoMember(25)] public RejectReason RejectReason;
        [ProtoMember(26)] public ReportCause ReportCause;
        [ProtoMember(27)] public Guid InstructionId { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(28)] public Guid ExternalOrderId;
        [ProtoMember(29)] public int ExecutionEngineMarketId { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(30)] public long OrderId;
        [ProtoMember(31)] public CancelReason CancelReason;
        [ProtoMember(32)] public long TxId;
        [ProtoMember(34)] public TimeInForce TimeInForce;
        [ProtoMember(35)] public string CancelledBy;
    }

[ProtoContract]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct TradeData
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)] public long TradeId;
        [ProtoMember(4)] public decimal Amount;
        [ProtoMember(5)] public decimal ExecutionPrice;
        [ProtoMember(7)] public OrderStatus OrderStatus;
        [ProtoMember(11)] public long AccountId;
        [ProtoMember(14)] public Guid MatchedOrderExternalId;
        [ProtoMember(16)] public long MatchedOrderId;
        [ProtoMember(17)] public decimal RemainingAmount;
    }
```

While trying to unmarshal the data I'm getting this error

```
proto: cannot parse invalid wire-format data
```

This is how I'm parsing the data:

```
_, err = sc.Subscribe("EXEC", func(m *stan.Msg) {
varr := &protos.Execution{}
err = proto.Unmarshal(m.Data, varr)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Err unmarshalling!: %v\n\n", err.Error())
} else {
    fmt.Printf("Received a message: %+v\n", varr)
}
```

A sample byte data I'm receiving from the server:

```
[5 85 0 0 0 56 1 66 3 8 144 78 74 2 8 1 82 2 8 1 104 197 192 132 194 159 143 219 237 8 176 1 25 184 1 11 208 1 1 218 1 18 9 133 66 138 247 239 67 93 77 17 176 192 189 75 170 203 186 145 226 1 18 9 133 66 138 247 239 67 93 77 17 176 192 189 75 170 203 186 145 232 1 1 240 1 25 128 2 25]
```

Adding more details:

This is how C# is sending data:

```
public async Task SendAsync(IFeedMessage msg)
{
    var subject = FeedSubject.ForMessage(msg);
    var data = msg.SerializeToArray();
    using (_metrics.FeedSendLatency.Start(new MetricTags("subject", subject.Value)))
    {
        await _connection.PublishAsync(subject, data);
    }
}
```

This is the structure of FeedMessage (which ExecutionReport is also inheriting indirectly)

```
public interface IFeedMessage
{
    FeedMessageType Type { get; }
    IFeedMessage Clone();
    void Reset();
}
```

This is how `SerializeToArray()` works:

```
public static ArraySegment<byte> SerializeToArray(this IFeedMessage message)
{
    return message.SerializeToMemory(new MemoryStream());
}

public static ArraySegment<byte> SerializeToMemory(this IFeedMessage message, MemoryStream stream)
{
    var start = stream.Position;
    message.Serialize(stream);
    return new ArraySegment<byte>(stream.GetBuffer(), (int)start, (int)(stream.Position - start));
}

public static void Serialize(this IFeedMessage message, Stream stream)
{
    stream.WriteByte((byte)message.Type);
    RuntimeTypeModel.Default.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, message, message.GetType(), PrefixStyle.Fixed32, 0);
}
```

I'm not sure what is the exact reason. But it seems that the proto file that I've written is wrong. I went through few posts facing the same error but most don't address the same issue. Let me know if any other detail is needed.

Please help me with this.

Comment: According to the [source code](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/blob/fc47fdd3d3fca5283fa9428ac94cf730236e4ca3/internal/impl/decode.go#L102-L123), the field number is `n := tag >> 3`. In your raw data, the first tag is `5`, and `n` will be 0, which is invalid (the `protowire.MinValidNumber` is `1`). The proto looks consistent with the C# code. In order to find out what's wrong, we need you to show how the C# side publish data to stan.

Comment: And please clarify which `stan` package you're using. Because `stan.Msg` in [this packaing](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/nats-io/stan.go) does not have the field `RawData`.

Comment: One interesting thing is that the last several bytes (`data := []byte{232, 1, 1, 240, 1, 25, 128, 2, 25}`) contains valid data (`ExecutionEngineMarketId:1 OrderId:25 TxId:25`). But it could be a coincidence.

Comment: @ZekeLu Yes, I was originally using Data instead of RawData. Have edited the code above. Also, your last point is interesting i.e. some part of the bytes array seems to contain valid data. Let me check and post the C# side publisher code.

Comment: `var data = msg.SerializeToArray()`, how is `msg.SerializeToArray` implemented? Can you log the data?

Comment: @ZekeLu I've added the code of SerializeToArray. Actually, I don't know C# and thought maybe it's a C# inbuilt method.

Comment: Thanks for the update! `SerializeToArray` is an extension method of `IFeedMessage`. The current code shows what the first byte (`5`) is. It's the value of `(byte)message.Type`. So obviously, we can not call `proto.Unmarshal(m.Data, varr)` directly. We have to drill down `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.SerializeWithLengthPrefix` to find out how to interpret the other bytes.

Comment: @ZekeLu You are right! Message type for ExecutionReport is 5. I'm reading about SerializeWithLengthPrefix now and how to deserialize in Go.

Comment: @ZekeLu What SerializeWithLengthPrefix does basically is it adds the length of the message before the bytes of the message. Can know more here: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/protobuf-in-c-net-part-3-using-length-prefixes/

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense now. I took a carefully look and found that you defined `decimal` and `Guid` in C# as `string` in proto. That's incorrect. After correcting these types, I can unmarshal the data now. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, I have managed to unmarshal the data.

**Notes**:

1. the data is prefixed with 5 bytes (this is totally unnecessary):

   - 1 byte for the message type
   - 4 bytes for the data length
2. the C# implementation uses the `decimal` and `Guid` data types that are specific to C#. (as commented in `bcl.proto`, cross-platform code should usually avoid them completely).

Here is the folder structure:

```
├── bcl.proto
├── execution.proto
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── main.go
└── protos
    ├── bcl.pb.go
    └── execution.pb.go
```

**bcl.proto**:

This file is copied from [github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/Tools/bcl.proto). It's required because the .NET implementation use `Decimal` and `Guid` from this proto file.

```
// The types in here indicate how protobuf-net represents certain types when using protobuf-net specific
// library features. Note that it is not *required* to use any of these types, and cross-platform code
// should usually avoid them completely (ideally starting from a .proto schema)

// Some of these are ugly, sorry. The TimeSpan / DateTime dates here pre-date the introduction of Timestamp
// and Duration, and the "well known" types should be preferred when possible. Guids are particularly
// awkward - it turns out that there are multiple guid representations, and I accidentally used one that
// I can only call... "crazy-endian". Just make sure you check the order!

// It should not be necessary to use bcl.proto from code that uses protobuf-net

syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "ProtoBuf.Bcl";
option go_package = "./protos";

package bcl;

message TimeSpan {
  sint64 value = 1; // the size of the timespan (in units of the selected scale)
  TimeSpanScale scale = 2; // the scale of the timespan [default = DAYS]
  enum TimeSpanScale {
    DAYS = 0;
    HOURS = 1;
    MINUTES = 2;
    SECONDS = 3;
    MILLISECONDS = 4;
    TICKS = 5;

    MINMAX = 15; // dubious
  }
}

message DateTime {
  sint64 value = 1; // the offset (in units of the selected scale) from 1970/01/01
  TimeSpanScale scale = 2; // the scale of the timespan [default = DAYS]
  DateTimeKind kind = 3; // the kind of date/time being represented [default = UNSPECIFIED]
  enum TimeSpanScale {
    DAYS = 0;
    HOURS = 1;
    MINUTES = 2;
    SECONDS = 3;
    MILLISECONDS = 4;
    TICKS = 5;

    MINMAX = 15; // dubious
  }
  enum DateTimeKind
  {
     // The time represented is not specified as either local time or Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).
     UNSPECIFIED = 0;
     // The time represented is UTC.
     UTC = 1;
     // The time represented is local time.
     LOCAL = 2;
   }
}

message NetObjectProxy {
  int32 existingObjectKey = 1; // for a tracked object, the key of the **first** time this object was seen
  int32 newObjectKey = 2; // for a tracked object, a **new** key, the first time this object is seen
  int32 existingTypeKey = 3; // for dynamic typing, the key of the **first** time this type was seen
  int32 newTypeKey = 4; // for dynamic typing, a **new** key, the first time this type is seen
  string typeName = 8; // for dynamic typing, the name of the type (only present along with newTypeKey)
  bytes payload = 10; // the new string/value (only present along with newObjectKey)
}

message Guid {
  fixed64 lo = 1; // the first 8 bytes of the guid (note:crazy-endian)
  fixed64 hi = 2; // the second 8 bytes of the guid (note:crazy-endian)
}

message Decimal {
  uint64 lo = 1; // the first 64 bits of the underlying value
  uint32 hi = 2; // the last 32 bis of the underlying value
  uint32 signScale = 3; // the number of decimal digits (bits 1-16), and the sign (bit 0)
}
```

**execution.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

package execution;

option go_package = "./protos";

import "bcl.proto";

enum OrderStatus {
  Working = 0;
  Rejected = 1;
  Cancelled = 2;
  Completed = 3;
}

enum OrderType {
  Limit = 0;
  Market = 1;
  StopLimit = 2;
  StopMarket = 3;
}

enum OrderSide {
  Buy = 0;
  Sell = 1;
}

enum RejectReason {
  NoRejection = 0;
  InstrumentNotFound = 1;
  OrderNotFound = 2;
  InvalidOrderType = 3;
  InvalidAccount = 4;
  InvalidSide = 5;
  InvalidAmount = 6;
  InvalidLimitPrice = 7;
  InvalidQuoteLimit = 8;
  InvalidActivationPrice = 9;
  InvalidTimeInForce = 10;
  MarketHalted = 11;
  MarketPaused = 12;
  NoCounterOrders = 13;
  MissingExpirationTime = 14;
  IncorrectExpirationTime = 15;
  InternalError = 16;
  IllegalStatusSwitch = 17;
  OrderAlreadyExists = 18;
  InstrumentNotReady = 19;
  ExternalSystemError = 20;
}

enum ReportCause {
  NONE = 0;
  NewOrder = 1;
  CancelOrder = 2;
  MassCancel = 3;
  Expiration = 4;
  Trigger = 5;
  MarketStatusChange = 6;
}

enum TimeInForce {
  GoodTillCancel = 0;
  ImmediateOrCancel = 1;
  FillOrKill = 2;
}

enum CancelReason {
  NotCancelled = 0;
  CancelledByTrader = 1;
  CancelledBySystem = 2;
  SelfMatchPrevention = 3;
  OrderTimeInForce = 4;
  Liquidation = 100;
}


message TradeData {
  int64 TradeId = 1;
  bcl.Decimal Amount = 4;
  bcl.Decimal ExecutionPrice = 5;
  OrderStatus OrderStatus = 7;
  int64 AccountId = 11;
  bcl.Guid MatchedOrderExternalId = 14;
  int64 MatchedOrderId = 16;
  bcl.Decimal RemainingAmount = 17;
}

message Execution {
  bytes Origin = 4;
  OrderSide Side = 7;
  bcl.Decimal RequestedPrice = 8;
  bcl.Decimal RequestedAmount = 9;
  bcl.Decimal RemainingAmount = 10;
  int64 ExecutedAt = 13;
  OrderStatus OrderStatus = 14;
  repeated TradeData Trades = 16;
  OrderType OrderType = 20;
  int64 Version = 22;
  int64 AccountId = 23;
  RejectReason RejectReason = 25;
  ReportCause ReportCause = 26;
  bcl.Guid InstructionId = 27;
  bcl.Guid ExternalOrderId = 28;
  int32 ExecutionEngineMarketId = 29;
  int64 OrderId = 30;
  CancelReason CancelReason = 31;
  int64 TxId = 32;
  TimeInForce TimeInForce = 34;
  string CancelledBy = 35;
}
```

**protos/**

The files in this folder are generated from the proto files with this command:

```
protoc --go_out=protos --go_opt=paths=source_relative bcl.proto execution.proto
```

**go.mod**

```
module mymodule.local

go 1.20

require google.golang.org/protobuf v1.30.0
```

**main.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "log"

    "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"

    "mymodule.local/protos"
)

func main() {
    data := []byte{5, 85, 0, 0, 0, 56, 1, 66, 3, 8, 144, 78, 74, 2, 8, 1, 82, 2, 8, 1, 104, 197, 192, 132, 194, 159, 143, 219, 237, 8, 176, 1, 25, 184, 1, 11, 208, 1, 1, 218, 1, 18, 9, 133, 66, 138, 247, 239, 67, 93, 77, 17, 176, 192, 189, 75, 170, 203, 186, 145, 226, 1, 18, 9, 133, 66, 138, 247, 239, 67, 93, 77, 17, 176, 192, 189, 75, 170, 203, 186, 145, 232, 1, 1, 240, 1, 25, 128, 2, 25}
    if len(data) < 5 {
        log.Fatal("data should contain at least 5 bytes")
    }
    messageType := data[0]
    length := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(data[1:5])
    data = data[5:]
    if length != uint32(len(data)) {
        log.Fatalf("invalid data length: %d", length)
    }
    execution := &protos.Execution{}

    err := proto.Unmarshal(data, execution)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Err unmarshalling!: %v", err)
    }

    log.Printf("message type: %d, message: %+v", messageType, execution)
}
```

Output of the data provided in the quetion:

```
2023/06/15 17:50:58 message type: 5, message: Side:Sell  RequestedPrice:{lo:10000}  RequestedAmount:{lo:1}  RemainingAmount:{lo:1}  ExecutedAt:638223043314917445  Version:25  AccountId:11  ReportCause:NewOrder  InstructionId:{lo:5574686611683820165  hi:10500929413443338416}  ExternalOrderId:{lo:5574686611683820165  hi:10500929413443338416}  ExecutionEngineMarketId:1  OrderId:25  TxId:25
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I want to upvote it a thousand times but can't since I don't have 15 reps yet. I was stuck at this for last two days but I'm able to parse it now :) Thanks a lot!